# How to get values of one key from multiple dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

This is the data I have in my `data.txt` file

```
{"setup": "test", "punchline": "ok", "numOfRatings": 0, "sumOfRatings": 0},
{"setup": "test2", "punchline": "ok2", "numOfRatings": 0, "sumOfRatings": 0}
```

How would I be able to get only data from every `setup` in the 
dictionaries using a loop?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Is this data in JSON format? It looks like it. If so, have you tried using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module? If it didn't work, what was the error message or problem? Showing what you've tried so far helps readers figure out what sort of guidance you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're getting the dictionaries into your text file in the first place, but if it's possible to drop the trailing commas, i.e.

```
{"setup": "test", "punchline": "ok", "numOfRatings": 0, "sumOfRatings": 0}
{"setup": "test2", "punchline": "ok2", "numOfRatings": 0, "sumOfRatings": 0}
```

Something like this may work for you:

```
def dicts_from_file(file):
    dicts_from_file = []
    with open(file,'r') as inf:
        for line in inf:
            dicts_from_file.append(eval(line))
    return dicts_from_file

def get_setups(dicts):
    setups = []
    for dict in dicts:
        for key in dict:
            if key == "setup":
                setups.append(dict[key])
    return setups

print get_setups(dicts_from_file("data.txt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    f = open('data')
    for line in f:
        d = ast.literal_eval(line)[0]
        print d['setup']
```

for this code you need to put ',' after every line because  ast.literal_eval(line) convert line into a tuple.

and if you do not have ',' after every dict then use this

```
f = open('data')
for line in f:
   d = ast.literal_eval(line)
   print d['setup']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if the line in your file is standard dict string.

```
def get_setup_from_file(file_name):
    result = []
    f = open(file_name, "r")
    for line in f.xreadlines():
        # or  line_dict = json.loads(line)
        line_dict = eval(line)  # if line end witch ',', try eval(line[0:-1])
        result.append(line_dict["setup"])
    return result
```

Wish this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

if it is standard dict string, try this:

```
with open(file,'r') as file_input:
    for line in file_input:
        print eval(line).get("setup")
```